# Using Javascript to hide words in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a sentence which I would like to be able to hide words by using Javascript. For example, hiding the first and 6th word or something. Coming from a PHP background my guess is that it would go something like this.

1. You have a DIV with a sentence in it.
2. You get the value of the DIV (the text sentence).
3. You split the text by spaces " " to get each word.
4. You then surround each word with a SPAN and id or class.
5. You place all the words with the spans around them back into the DIV.
6. Then from user interaction (or timeout events) you can hide each SPAN[text]SPAN as needed.

Is this the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Do the spaces that the words that were hidden collapse? or is it left open with white space?

Comment: I would want to preserver spaces so my guess is that the spaces would just be re-inserted with each SPAN that was placed back into the DIV.

Comment: Sorry, I miss-read your question. I would like the space that each word occupied to remain intact rather than shrinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it exactly as you described. In fact, I actually did:

```
<div>
The dog jumps over the log.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function boxWords(textNode) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        // trim leading and trailing whitespace to avoid empty elements
        words = textNode.nodeValue.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g, '').split(' ');

    for(var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; ++i) {
        frag.appendChild(document.createElement('span').appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(words[i])).parentNode);
        frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
    }

    textNode.parentNode.replaceChild(frag, textNode);
}

var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
boxWords(div.firstChild);

// underline the 4th word
div.getElementsByTagName('span')[3].style.textDecoration = 'underline';
</script>
```

Comment: Very nice, now I just need to figure out how to retain the white space when hiding an element.

Comment: instead of style.textDecoration = 'underline';
use style.visibility='hidden'

Comment: Well, that hides it but I need to retain the whitespace that the word occupied.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure what purpose steps 4->6 serve? If you got the seperated words in step 3 then you can retain that array and always have access to the appropriate word when you need to do something with it.

Your way you still have to figure out which span/id/class to mess with when you want to do something. You're essentially creating the same problem for yourlsef in a different format,

Comment: Well, like I said, if I wish to hide the first and 6th word or something then my guess is that they would have to be DOM objects that can be "hidden" with display: none.

Comment: sure, but wrap them when you need to and when you know exactly which one you'll be needing. Not grabbing them all, wrapping them and then still being faced with the problem of finding the one you need all over again.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you're talking about now - one of the events you want to be able to consider is the possibility of clicking a single word and getting an effect, yes? In that case your solution is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general idea makes sense yes...

Get the innerhtml of the div.. split it by " " and then for each word in the value put it into a div with a unique id... you can keep the relative size of the word in the space by making invisible, or you can make the sentence collapse by making the innerhtml = "".

```
function divclick(id)
{
    //document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="hidden";
        // OR 
    //document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
}
```

As for getting the div split and re-displayed into its own individual word divs... that shouldnt be to big of a deal... the only think you have to take into consideration is what events are causing the words to dissappear or appear.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what event will cause the words to disappear - it could be a mouseclick, timeout, or onLoad. I just want to make sure I have some easy way of accessing the words when it is time for them to be hidden.